# Qt Creator can't find library files in the search path

Tags: c++, qt, c++17, mingw

When I compile the release target, everything is built correctly and I can run the program via windows explorer (the install script copies all the libraries to the .exe folder).

The problem that I am having, is that the program does not run inside QtCreator (in both debug and release) unless I manually copy the libraries to the .exe folder. This was not how it used to work but somehow, since I upgraded to Qt6 and start to use mingw instead of vc++, this behaviour started to happen.

There is an option in the project tab to "Add build library search to the PATH" that apparently is intended for exactly this reason (sip copying the libraries every time we compile), but somehow this is not working. I see the PATH change in the Environment form, but the program just crashes on loading with a "This application was unable to start correctly". If I copy the libraries and try again, it works.

Answer (score 0):

So it turns out that it can't find just the onnxruntime.dll library. I assume that it has trouble finding any library that does not start with lib from the path. My solution for now was to copy just this file to the .exe folder.